# Prove by induction every $ n\:\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

Prove by induction for every $ n\:\in \mathbb{N}$

$\frac{1}{1\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 7}+\frac{1}{7\cdot 10}\:+\:...\:+\:\frac{1}{\left(3n+4\right)\left(3n+7\right)}\:=\:\frac{\left(n+2\right)}{3n+7}$

I'm stuck at the basis step. for $n=1$, $\frac{1}{1\cdot 4}$ is not equal to $\frac{1+2}{\:3\cdot 1+7}$.

How do I continue?

Comment: You don't get $\frac{1}{1\cdot 4}$ for $n=1$

Comment: Why not? @jjagmath Why in this example $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\:...+\:\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}\:=\:\frac{n}{n+1}$ I can look only in the first addend and say that it equals to what's over the right side?

Comment: Because in that example you get only the first term when you set $n=1$. In this case you have $\frac{1}{1\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 7}+\frac{1}{7\cdot 10}+\cdots + \frac{1}{(3n+4)(3n+7)}$ which means "take the sum until the last term is $\frac{1}{(3n+4)(3n+7)}$"

Answer (score 3):

Notice what the last term for $n$ on the left side is. So for $n=1$ you have on the left $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{7\cdot 10}$

Comment: I can't undrestand how, what do I get for n=2 and n=3? What is the calculation?

Comment: And I don't understand, how does this apply to another example I saw : $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\:...+\:\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}\:=\:\frac{n}{n+1}$ when here I thought that for n=1, $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Comment: This is the case, since the last term in this particular sum is $\frac{1}{n\cdot (n+1)}$, however in the case above, the last term is $\frac{1}{\left(3n+4\right)\left(3n+7\right)} $, so you want to make sure to go until you reach this last term. Plug in $n=1$ and the last term is  $\frac{1}{7\cdot 10} $

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\mathrm{1}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{4}}+\frac{1}{\mathrm{4}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{7}}+....+\frac{1}{(3n+4)(3n+7)}+\frac{1}{(3n+3+4)(3n+3+7)}=\frac{(n+2)}{(3n+7)}+\frac{1}{(3n+7)(3n+10)}$$
Adding the terms in RHS, you get

$$\frac{1}{\mathrm{1}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{4}}+\frac{1}{\mathrm{4}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{7}}+....+\frac{1}{(3n+4)(3n+7)}+\frac{1}{(3n+3+4)(3n+3+7)}=\frac{(3n+7)(n+3)}{(3n+7)(3n+10)}$$
the RHS is $\frac{(n+1+2)}{(3n+3+7)}$
Hence proven by induction.

the important point in this is that n is not 1 in the beginning, it is -1. The equation is true even if you put -1, but that is not a natural number, so you don't need to prove from that point. You can instead start with n=1 and consider first 3 terms in LHS.